# regex patterns and lists in python

Tags: python, regex, list, findall

I have hunted around various other posts and although there are some useful tips I haven't found a similar problem to mine so I thought I would ask.
I have generated the following list:

```
data2 = ['AN1_OUT,24','AN2_OUT,13','AN3_OUT,14','AN4_OUT,15']
```

What I want to do is identify the setting (AN1_OUT etc..) and the value (2,13 etc...) that accompanies it. I have successfully identified the setting by using the good old 'if-elif' as I only need to know this setting, however, I now need to separate out the value. So far I am using:

```
data3 = re.findall('[0-9]{2}',data2[i])
byte1 = map(lambda n: int(n[:2]),data3)
```

This is in a for loop that runs through all of the elements in the data2 list (4 in this example). for each 'i' I am getting the following:

```
[24]
[13]
[14]
[15]
```

I know this is what I would expect, however, the problem arises when the value is a single digit such as:

```
'AN1_OUT,2'
```

In this case I miss that value and it is not printed. I tried changing the regex in the data3 function to:

```
data3 = re.findall('[0-9]{1,2}',data2[i])
```

However the problem with this is that it picks up the digit in AN1_OUT, AN2_OUT etc.. so I end up with:

```
[1,2]
[2,13]
[3,14]
[4,15]
```

I have looked at various different ways to solve it but it is proving very elusive. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `.split(',')[:-1]` to get everything after the comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `$` at the end to make it match only at the end of the input string:

```
'[0-9]{1,2}$'
```

You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
'\\d{1,2}$'
```

To avoid escape use raw string (`r'raw string'`):

```
r'\d{1,2}$'

>>> re.findall(r'\d{1,2}$', 'AN3_OUT,14')
['14']

>>> re.findall(r'\d+$', 'AN3_OUT,14')
['14']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-behind to fetch the digit preceded by *comma*. Also, you can use `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]{1,2}`, id you can have more digits.

```
data3 = re.findall(r'(?<=,)[0-9]+',data2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the strings you've described without using regular expressions. Just split on the comma!

```
for item in data2:
    setting, value = item.split(',')
    if setting == 'AN1_OUT':
        value = int(value)
        # do stuff with value
```